# How to automatically connect to TCP server after disconnection in netty

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, netty

I have a scenario where I am establishing TCP connection using netty NIO, suppose server went down than how can I automatically connect to server when it comes up again ? 
Or Is there any way to attach availability listener on server ?

Comment: Interesting question, but I think it's possible just doing a ping to server to get availability

Comment: But in that case I need to kept one of my thread busy in just checking availability of server, lets see if someone have any idea about it

Comment: Try using the ChannelInactive method in a handler

Comment: Same way you created the original connection. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP But how can I detected the server is up again so there may be a situation that server comes back after few hours than in that case I need to keep retrying till that time, So basically I am looking for any event from Server which states that it is up & running again ? Or Anything in netty which automatically handle this retry mechanism, Hope now it make sense to you

Answer (score 4):

You can have a `DisconnectionHandler`, as the first thing on your client pipeline, that reacts on `channelInactive` by immediately trying to reconnect or scheduling a reconnection task.

For example,

```
public class DisconnectionHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void channelInactive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception   {

    Channel channel = ctx.channel();
    
    /* If shutdown is on going, ignore */
    if (channel.eventLoop().isShuttingDown()) return;
    
    ReconnectionTask reconnect = new ReconnectionTask(channel);
    reconnect.run();
  }

}
```

The `ReconnectionTask` would be something like this:

```
public class ReconnectionTask implements Runnable, ChannelFutureListener {

    Channel previous;
    
    public ReconnectionTask(Channel c) {
        this.previous = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
         Bootstrap b = createBootstrap();
         b.remoteAddress(previous.remoteAddress())
          .connect()
          .addListener(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
        if (!future.isSuccess()) {
            // Will try to connect again in 100 ms.
            // Here you should probably use exponential backoff or some sort of randomization to define the retry period.
            previous.eventLoop()
                    .schedule(this, 100, MILLISECONDS); 
            return;
        }
        // Do something else when success if needed.
    }
}
```

Check here for an example of [Exponential Backoff library](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/client/util/ExponentialBackOff.html).

Comment: Thanks Leo, It make sense,Do you know is there any underlying feature in netty which gives me same functionality , Any Connection settings option?

Comment: Not that I know. I would think of something within the ChannelPool (http://netty.io/4.0/api/index.html?io/netty/channel/pool/package-summary.html) implementation, but it doesn't seem to be the case.